# Distinguish between vector and bitmap images with python-pptx

Tags: python, bitmap, powerpoint, vector-graphics, python-pptx

I have a PowerPoint file (.pptx) which includes both vector and bitmap graphics.

I am trying to automatically identify and mark the bitmap images with a thick red border line. The vector images should not be marked.

I wrote the following script to place a red border around the images:

```py
from pptx import Presentation
from pptx.dml.color import RGBColor
from pptx.util import Pt

prs = Presentation("test.pptx")

for slide_id, slide in enumerate(prs.slides):
    slide_number = slide_id + 1
    for shape_id, shape in enumerate(slide.shapes):
        # print(slide_number, shape.shape_type)
        if shape.shape_type == 13:  # if shape is an image
            # print(slide_number, shape.image.content_type)
            if shape.image.content_type == "image/png":
                line = shape.line
                line.color.rgb = RGBColor(255, 0, 0)
                line.width = Pt(3.0)
            if shape.image.content_type == "image/jpeg":
                line = shape.line
                line.color.rgb = RGBColor(255, 0, 0)
                line.width = Pt(3.0)

prs.save("out.pptx")
```

Problem: also the vector images are marked with a red border, because their shape.image.content_type == "image/png".

How can I filter out vector images?

Comment: PNG is not a vector format. Are they being transformed by PowerPoint?

Comment: The vector image was imported in the .pptx deck from a vector format (SVG), and can also be exported again from the .pptx deck to a vector format (SVG). The exported image is an actual vector format: it can be scaled to a very large format without showing pixelation.

Because of this, I assume that PowerPoint does keep the vector/path information, but potentially renders this as PNG as well.

Comment: It makes sense that PowerPoint would store the PNG because earlier PowerPoint versions cannot render SVG and it needs a lowest-common-denominator version to assure the presentation can be loaded by all supported versions. If you inspect the XML for that shape with `print(shape._element.xml)` you might uncover some hints. I expect it stores both the source SVG and the rendered-at-current-dimensions PNG.

Comment: Thanks @scanny , `shape._element.xml` indeed contained references to "svg"! I will post my solution below.

Comment: Related, and I'm not sure if it's been 100% answered above, can python-pptx import SVG directly? Today md2pptx converts to PNG under the covers and sets the dimensions on doing so.

Not doing the conversion would obviously be better.

Comment: I do not know. I have only used my script to scan and edit PowerPoint decks that were created manually by people through the MS PowerPoint app.

Answer (score 2):

`shape._element.xml` contains references to "svg", which can be used to distinguish between vector and bitmap images.

Full working example:

```py
from pptx import Presentation
from pptx.dml.color import RGBColor
from pptx.util import Pt
from pptx.enum.dml import MSO_LINE


def mark_shape(shape):
    line = shape.line
    line.color.rgb = RGBColor(255, 0, 0)
    line.width = Pt(3.0)
    line.dash_style = MSO_LINE.DASH
    return


def check_bitmap(shape):
    if shape.shape_type == 13:  # if shape is an image
        if shape.image.content_type == "image/png":
            if "asvg" not in shape._element.xml:
                return True
        if shape.image.content_type == "image/jpeg":
            return True
    return False


def check_group(shape):
    if shape.shape_type == 6:  # if shape is a group
        return True


def check_and_mark(shapes):
    for shape_id, shape in enumerate(shapes):
        if check_bitmap(shape):  # if bitmap, mark
            mark_shape(shape)
        if check_group(shape):  # if group, traverse recursively
            check_and_mark(shape.shapes)


def mark_bitmaps(prs):
    for slide_id, slide in enumerate(prs.slides):
        slide_number = slide_id + 1
        check_and_mark(slide.shapes)


prs = Presentation("in.pptx")

mark_bitmaps(prs)

prs.save("out.pptx")
```

Comment: what does the shape XML look like? What have you deduced about where the SVG lives and why it appears as PNG?